# Were these edit rollbacks appropriate?

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks, specific-edit

I've answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68312881/how-to-get-element-whose-onclick-has-been-fired-on-click-of-any-child-element) and after answering and accepting the answer, the poster requested an edit which removed some names that are probably a brand which is in development. I accepted the change because I noticed that the question was also changed.

But today I got a notification that both the question and the answer got a rollback to a version WITH the brand names. Do I need to re-edit the question and answer? Or is this a legitimate rollback?

Comment: @JeanneDark Unforunately not, because I don't have the option to rollback the rollback. And to add to that; Is it legitimate to undo the rollback?

Comment: You can rollback to any revision via the [revision page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68313031/revisions) (there is a gray "rollback" link next to each revision).

Comment: @janw You're right. I was looking for the rollback function on the edit I wanted to rollback. But that leaves the part about if it was a legitimate edit unanswered.

Comment: I smell a bigger issue here: the OP of the linked question is probably looking for possible revision redaction instead.

Comment: Possibly, although I don't see much in there that could be problematic.

Comment: @AndrewT. Bigger issue for me is *"Meantime I am trying to get deleted this question."* - OP is trying to get their question (which could potentially be helpful for others) deleted simply because they weren't thinking when they were asking the question :facepalm: (or because they were looking to delete it as soon as they got an answer, which is just, bleugh)

Comment: @Nick I interpreted that part from OP as "_As long as the brand name is visible, I want to get rid of the question_" because he himself couldn't edit it apparently. As of now, the brand names are removed and I believe that's the only thing OP wanted

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Missed that comment as it wasn't on the edit in question :p was on the editors answer, as for not being able to edit, that's because it was being rejected by answer author, which is fine, the suggested edit wasn't an improvement, them calling out people abusing their edit [review] privileges (now deleted comment) is simply wrong

Comment: @DouwedeHaan well, the brand name is still visible on the edit history though... but don't tell the OP :x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP edited their question to change some `id`s in the code. The change is pretty insignificant, and makes the code more readable. They also suggested that change to the answers existing on that question, among which is your answer.

Then, an answerer decided they didn't like the edit, and looking at the comments under their answer, they don't seem to think that making the ids match again is an "improvement"...

I disagree.

I also don't think an answerer has the right to revert an edit the OP made to the question, just because it makes their answer *slightly inconsistent*.

So, to answer your question:

No, those rollbacks were unwarranted.

Now, there should be a "rollback" link in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68313031/revisions) of your answer:

[image]
(Click the rollback link on the revision you want)

Comment: Thanks, that was my thought as well, but I wanted to check whether or not it was a legitimate rollback. I've made the changes to both the question and answer again, as per wish of the person who posted the question.